# No ejecuta clase Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy pasándome un proyecto (En Eclipse) de Sockets que tengo en otro paquete dentro del mismo proyecto a Sockets con Hilos(un paquete nuevo dentro del mismo proyecto) y desde el primer intento de ejecución en las clases del paquete nuevo me salta un error ¿Alguna sugerencia de porque puede ocurrir esto? pego la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando un proyecto tiene múltiples clases con un `main()`, debes indicarle a eclipse *CUAL* de esos main es el principal, porque si no, no sabe qué ejecutar. De hecho, creo que con uno solo ya debes indicárselo la primera vez que ejecutas el proyecto... no estoy seguro, porque eclipse no me gusta nada y lo evito siempre que puedo. Pero imagino que será que te faltan configurarle la clase principal.

Comment: En el panel de Eclipse arriba verás que hay una especie de "boton de play" son 3. Pues justo tienes que pusar al boton con una fechita hacia abajo. Desde hay te dejará selecionar la clase que quieres ejecutar del paquete

Comment: En *Run Configurations > Main* verifica *Main class*.